# PHPStorm Debug Tool window is disabled?

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

This morning I encountered a strange problem that I couldn't find the answer for on Google: my 
debug window has become disabled. It was working fine last night and I don't believe I have modified any config files since.

Does anybody know how can I reenable the window?

[Screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKYGM.png)

Comment: Debug window is available during debug session ONLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops simple fix! I just set a break point inside of one of my unit tests and then ran PHPUnit - the Debug tool window became available and appeared back inside of the dock.

Comment: This has worked for me so far, but recently I toggled to skip all breakpoints and now it doesn't open anymore.